# How to find deceleration in android using either GPS data or accelerometer?

Tags: java, android

I am working on android app where I need to find hard breaks with threshold -3 meter/sec2. Can it be done using speed variation or accelerometer?

Comment: GPS is not accurate enough for this, that is for sure

Comment: The sample rate for GPS would be way too low. An accelerometer would be able to measure it, but im doubtful the ones inside a phone would give you the accuracy you need

Answer (score 0):

Speed variation would work if you would move for a long time at the same speed, so that the phone can recognize that you do so. And then the phone should be able to know when you start slowing down, and when you stop. And I don't think that it is accurate enough with GPS to do so.

The accelerometer would work, but it depends on how accurate that one is. I know that the iPhone would be enough accurate, but I doubt that a lot of Android phones can do this too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Can you tell me if is there any algorithm to process the raw accelerometer data to detect acceleration or deceleration? And how accurate it would be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use gps data, find the speed and then calculate acceleration.
But I am not sure how to process the data because if you calculate only with two consecutive entries it will not be enough to find the accurate acceleration.